# Architecture for tracking a remote value

Tags: architecture, distributed-system

The problem is as follows:
At point A (say a server or a database), we can query/aggregate for a value that takes time (maybe seconds). Once we know the value, we want to be able to send events about changes in the value from point A to point B. B is the remote location that is tracking this value.

So, B queries A for the value once and then consumes a stream of diff events to keep the value at B converging to the right value at A.

The problem is that this stream of messages is persistent (e.g. messages in a Kafka topic). Node B can crash and would need to be restarted and must not apply any diff twice or miss any diff events.

What are the possible alternatives for architecture of this application? Timestamp checks to ignore diff are going to introduce flakiness and it would be very hard to understand the whole system. Moreover, that would be *wrong*.

If this question isn't appropriate for stackoverflow, it would be great if you can comment and let me know a better place for it.

There are multiple instances of A that are acting independently and updating the value in a shared storage. Versioning diffs with multiple source instances makes it difficult because source instances fire and forget diff events.

To give you an example:
Let's say we are tasked with maintaing a priority queue of agents working in a company's support team. These agents are assigned tickets to work on. They resolve tickets. We must faily assign issues to agents. So, we need to maintain the count of issues that are currently assigned to every agent. Each ticket has an assignee. So, to get the count of tickets assigned to an agent, we query the tickets table for rows where the assignee is the agent. Once we have queried the table, we would consume diff events (emitted every time the agent is assigned a new ticket or resolves an existing ticket).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issue of not sending diffs twice by hashing (or versioning) the value on which the diff is applied (and sending the hash with the diff). Therefore B should only apply an incoming diff if the hash/version matches the hash/version of B's current value. This way A can freely send the same diff multiple times.

If B is in a state where no incoming diffs match the hash/version of B's current value, B can decide to reacquire the full value from A. Either that or A can periodically broadcast out the full value (perhaps compressed if it is large) to 'rebase' all B's.

It is also worth considering if all this effort is necessary and whether in fact you could simply broadcast the full value (perhaps compressed). If the data is to be distributed widely you could have caching servers in each region (you could also do this with the diff approach as well).

Comment: I agree with the4thamigo_uk. Versioning is a pretty standard approach.

Comment: Okay. So, the source and target both maintain versions and target node applies only diffs that are sent for the current version it has. 

The problem with this would be that the source will never send the update again. There are multiple sources that are not coordinating with each other and all update data in the db.

Comment: Modifying my question to add the point about multiple sources.

Comment: I'm confused. Please can you be more clear in the question. Perhaps an explicit scenario detailing the interactions between A B and the database might help.

Comment: @the4thamigo_uk Adding an example scenario.

Comment: Hmm... still not clear to me Im afraid. Lets break this down. Let H be one or more human agents. D be the database. My understanding is that H uses service A to change the ticket statuses in D. There are multiple A's, but is that one per agent, or just arbitrary number of A? Then, each B queries A for ticket-totals-per-agent, and then receives a stream of diffs from A. What precisely is B, why does it need this stream of totals? How does B decide which A to connect to? How does each A keep up to date with the latest data in D? Also, What service assigns tickets in D to H, or is it manual?

Comment: Also why cant you just have a separate (single) service C that reads the data from D and then sends out a single stream of diffs.

Comment: B needs a stream of diffs to maintain say a priority queue of agents based on the current number of issues assigned to them. It cannot query A all the time because that query can be expensive so it queries once and then wants to consume diffs to keep things updated. 

All components are communicating through a message broker. So, diffs get sent over topics that B is subscribing to and hence doesn't need to worry about where it came from.

Comment: The idea of having a separate service that reads data from D and sends out diffs looks interesting. If the database provides triggers, it would be a cleaner approach than this.